# How to modify scss file in already builded angular project

Tags: angular, sass

I want to modify content of scss file in already builded angular project.

After updating the scss file , for exemple changing values of declared variable , i don't see any change in the pages where i used the scss.

Comment: There is no scss in a build project. The compiler creates normal css during build time..

Comment: I have an scss file in assets for exemple where i've made changes , how could we rebuild the project to change the styles.css generated when building by the new one, without using the regular build of angular.

Comment: I don’t really understand your motivation here. You don’t have the source anymore? If so, you could write an overwrite css file and include it in the index.html..?

Comment: I want to add an scss file containing variables , for exemple a variable to change the color of a button. If i Change the value of this variable the color of the button will change. In the build folder i didn't find a solution.

Comment: See my first comment..

Comment: hi @achrafbenalaya, have you found any solution? I have been facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution by adding those line under angular.json

[image]

I also create a json file containing the names of css files that i already created

I also created a method that i load onInit of the app.component.ts

```
getAndLoadTheme() {
    this.httpClient.get("/assets/configuration/themes.json").subscribe(
          (data) => this.loadThemeSuccess(data),
          (error) => this.loadThemeFailed()
        )
      }
    
       private loadThemeSuccess(data: any) {
        let themeList: any;
        themeList = data;
        if (themeList.theme) {
          this.loadTheme(themeList.theme);
        }
      }
    
private loadTheme(cssFileName: string) {
        const head = this.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        let themeLink = this.document.getElementById('client-theme') as HTMLLinkElement;
        if (themeLink) {
          themeLink.href = cssFileName;
        } else {
          const style = this.document.createElement('link');
          style.id = 'client-theme';
          style.rel = 'stylesheet';
          style.href = `${cssFileName}`;
          head.appendChild(style);
        }
      }
```